# Login via enter button

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I have login form and it works fine, but I don't know how to make it work via enter buttom. I did try to make it with JS, but it didn't work for some reason.

Also I think I made horrible code for login :(, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Make the sign in input a type of `submit`. Like this,

```
<input type="submit" class="zzzz" onclick="auth()" value="sign in"/>
```

This should fix the issue. It's a type of `button` currently which doesn't get triggered on submitting enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add `required` bellow 2 input

```
<input name="userName" required="required" placeholder="E-mail" id="username" type="text">
<input name="password" required="required" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password">
```

And then change input type bellow your submit input field

```
<input type="submit" class="zzzz" onclick="auth()" value="sign in"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but now i have to fix styles. 
Here is working example! https://www.xeovo.com/404
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually there is new problem, if i use wrong name/pass after hitting enter its going to refresh whole page.

Comment: @Derek it is not understandable. Show your auth() function

Comment: @Derek i thinks need to your js code as a `auth()` function

Answer (score -1):

Make button of input type submit and add this attribute to your form

```
<form onsubmit="return(false);">
```

so that it works with your javascript